# Bulma navbar dropdown menu opening in the navbar with scroll bar

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, navbar, bulma

So I made a navbar dropdown menu, (http://bulma.io/documentation/components/navbar/) which works, but I want it to **drop the menu outside of the navbar**, so you don't have to scroll it inside of the navbar. Want it to like freefall on top of the other content on my page. Does anyone know what rules I can define to make this happen?
 I might have overlooked some info regarding this, in their documentation, but I've tried a bunch of css and html, to no success. 
Thanks

```
           <div class="nav-right nav-menu fa-lg">
            <a class="navbar-item" href="#about">About</a>
            <div class="navbar-item has-dropdown is-active">
                <a class="navbar-item navbar-link">Locations</a>
                <div class="navbar-dropdown">
                    <a id= class="navbar-item">Stockholm</a>
                    <a class="navbar-item">Copenhagen</a>
                    <hr class="navbar-divider">
                    <div class="navbar-item">
                    Norway <3
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <a class="navbar-item" href="#social">Social</a>    


        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed, with css:

```
.nav-right {overflow-y:visible}

.navbar-item, .nav-right{overflow-x:visible}
```